# Is it possible to (partially) implement an abstract method and still require derived classes to also implement it?

Tags: c#, abstract-methods

Here's a prototype of what I'd like to do, except that I realize that it can't work the way I've written it:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Merlinia.CommonClasses
{
   public abstract class JustTesting<TItem> : KeyedCollection<string, TItem>
   {
      protected override string GetKeyForItem(TItem anItem)
      {
         return GetKeyForItem(anItem).ToUpperInvariant();
      }

      protected new abstract string GetKeyForItem(TItem anItem);
   }
}
```

Now I do realize that by changing the name of the abstract method I require in the derived classes that it does work:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Merlinia.CommonClasses
{
   public abstract class JustTesting<TItem> : KeyedCollection<string, TItem>
   {
      protected override string GetKeyForItem(TItem anItem)
      {
         return NewGetKeyForItem(anItem).ToUpperInvariant();
      }

      protected abstract string NewGetKeyForItem(TItem anItem);
   }
}
```

It's just that I'd prefer that the method name was the same, GetKeyForItem, in all of the classes. Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, and it would be very confusing if you could - after all, anyone reading *just* the top and bottom classes (not your abstract middle) would assume they were overriding the method in the *top* class.

Comment: @JonSkeet: OK, thanks. (Post it as an answer if you want points for it. :-)

Comment: It's not possible to do so, although it's possible to use explicit interface implementations the outer call (i.e. the 'partially' implemented method) will only be available through a reference of the interface itself. So the best thing to do is to provide another name to the second method, it's actually presented in the framework itself at `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`.

Comment: This is close enough to the *Template Method* pattern, which you could search. At a high level, it's essentially an abstract class with a non-virtual method that invokes virtual and abstract methods that derived classes must implement. It's useful for when you need to specify an algorithm without initially filling in all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert an extra class and an internal helper function in the hierarchy to do this.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Merlinia.CommonClasses
{
   public abstract class JustTestingBase<TItem> : KeyedCollection<string, TItem>
   {
      internal JustTestingBase()
      {
        // so that other assemblies cannot misuse this as their own base class
      }

      protected sealed override string GetKeyForItem(TItem anItem)
      {
         return GetKeyForItemHelper(anItem).ToUpperInvariant();
      }

      internal abstract string GetKeyForItemHelper(TItem anItem);
   }

   public abstract class JustTesting<TItem> : JustTestingBase<TItem>
   {
      protected new abstract string GetKeyForItem(TItem anItem);

      internal override string GetKeyForItemHelper(TItem anItem)
      {
        return GetKeyForItem(anItem);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks, that does the trick. But now on reflection, I think I'll take Jon Skeet's advice and just rename the method that is required in my derived classes.